# Padding of 802.11 packet with 0's in libpcap

Tags: network, wifi, sniffer, wireshark, packet

I am trying to send probe request to Access Points.But whenever I send a probe request packet it is padded with 0's i.e I see two packets on wireshark for every packet I send : a non-padded packet and a padded packet with 0's at the end.The padding changes the meaning of the tags in the packet and wireshark declares the second packet as a malformed packet.How do I remove this padding.Also why do I see two packets even though I am sending only one.

Here is the packet function that creates the packet:

```
int build_beacon(char *buf, struct network_t *n) {
    char *b = buf;
    /* prepend a minimal radiotap header */
    memset(b, 0x00, 13);
    b[2] = 13;
    b+=4;
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x04\x80\x02\x00", 4); /*Set flags*/
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x02", 1); /*Set bit rate*/
    b+=4;
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x40\x00\x00\x00", 4); /* IEEE802.11 probe request */
    b = append_to_buf(b, n->dst, sizeof(mac_t)); /* destination */
    b = append_to_buf(b, n->mac, sizeof(mac_t)); /* source */
    b = append_to_buf(b, n->mac, sizeof(mac_t)); /* BSSID */

        /* sequence number */
    *(b++) = n->seq >> 8;
    *(b++) = n->seq & 0x00FF;
    n->seq++;


    *(b++) = 0; /* tag essid */
    *(b++) = strlen(n->ssid);
    b = append_str(b, n->ssid);

    /*supported rates*/
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x01\x08\x02\x04\x0b\x16\x0c\x12\x18\x24", 10); 

    /*add channel*/
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x03\x01", 2); /* the channel we are currently on.*/ 
    *(b++) = n->channel;


    *(b++) = 10; /* tag request info element essid */
    *(b++) = 3;  /*size of request info*/
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x00\x07\xdd", 3);

    /*HT capability*/
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x2d\x1a\x3c\x09\x17\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00", 28); 

    /*extended supported rates*/
    b = append_to_buf(b, "\x32\x04\x30\x48\x60\x6c", 6); 
    return (b-buf);
}
```

Here is a snapshot of the two packets:

[image: Wireshark snapshot]

Here is the packet without padding:

[image: No padding]

Here is the packet with padded 0's.The colored mark is where padding starts.
[image: Padded]

Comment: This is not an InfoSec question, but a wireless networking/programming question.

Answer (score -1):

While i was reading your question i assumed you'd be on wireless, which is a broadcast medium. I assume you're also capturing on all interfaces.

Take note `b = append_to_buf(b, "\x32\x04\x30\x48\x60\x6c", 6);` there are six times 00 appended